# ag-grid react on page change it should make an api call every time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

so I am using AG-Grid React enterprise version **29.3.4** and server side row model. I am stuck with this pagination related issue which is when I go to last page it makes an api call and then i move to second last page then it is making 2 api calls (one for 2nd page and one for second last page) concurrently. so I have set
`maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests={1}`
but then the problem is that it is making 2nd page api call first and then not making 2nd last page api call at all.

so here is some snippet which might help you guys to understand better...

```
<AgGridReact
    rowModelType='serverSide'
    rowSelection='multiple'
    enableSorting={true}
    enableFilter={true}
    floatingFilter={true}
    enableColResize={true}
    pagination={true}
    paginationPageSize={25}
    domLayout='autoHeight'
    cacheBlockSize={25}
    maxBlocksInCache={0}
    maxConcurrentDatasourceRequests={1}
    columnDefs={columnDefs}
    rowData={rowData}
    sideBar={sideBar}
    suppressMenuHide={suppressMenuHide}
    onGridReady={onGridReady}
    defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
    onPaginationChanged={onPaginationChanged}
    rowHeight={rowHeight}
/>
```

```
onGridReady = (params) => {
    this.gridApi = params.api
    const datasource = this.getServerSideDatasource()
    // register datasource with the grid
    this.gridApi.setServerSideDatasource(datasource);
  }
```

I am making api call inside getServerSideDatasource() inside return getRows()
so I want to make api calls every time page is changed and not cache it. so how can i acheive that behaviour?

Comment: Hi Same here any update?